# VBA OutputTo PDF is saving blank reports too

Tags: vba, ms-access

The code below generates PDF reports for supervisors who have employees expiring between StartDate and StopDate fields on a form. I am getting multiple reports for supervisors who do not have employees expiring in that range, blank reports essentially. The code also puts out the correct reports that have data.

How can I prevent OutputTo from saving the blank reports?

**SQL for reference query (qry_Distinct_Supervisors):**

```
PARAMETERS StartDate DateTime, StopDate DateTime;
SELECT DISTINCT qry_Base_For_All.Supervisor, qry_Base_For_All.LID, qry_Base_For_All._Status, qry_Base_For_All.LASTNAME, qry_Base_For_All.FIRSTNAME, qry_Base_For_All.[End Date]
FROM qry_Base_For_All
WHERE (((qry_Base_For_All.Supervisor) Is Not Null) AND ((qry_Base_For_All.LASTNAME) Is Not Null) AND ((qry_Base_For_All.[End Date]) Between [StartDate] And [StopDate]));
```

**SQL for Report**

```
SELECT DISTINCT qry_Base_For_All.L_ID, qry_Base_For_All.LASTNAME, qry_Base_For_All.FIRSTNAME, qry_Base_For_All.P_ID, qry_Base_For_All.Company, qry_Base_For_All.[End Date], qry_Base_For_All.Supervisor, qry_Base_For_All.Title
FROM qry_Base_For_All
WHERE (((qry_Base_For_All.[End Date]) Between [Forms]![frm_Bldg_Access]![StartDate] And [Forms]![frm_Bldg_Access]![StopDate]) AND ((qry_Base_For_All.Title) Like "*" & "outsource" & "*"));
```

**VBA to save reports**

```
Private Sub btn_Print_Report_Click()
   'split report into PDFs named after supervisor and open a separate email with each report attached

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim mypath As String
    Dim temp As String
    Dim qry As QueryDef
    Dim StartDate As DAO.Parameter
    Dim StopDate As DAO.Parameter


    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set qry = db.QueryDefs("qry_Distinct_Supervisors")
    mypath = "C:\Users\cw52450\Desktop\Test Exports\"
    qry.Parameters("StartDate").Value = Forms!frm_Bldg_Access!StartDate
    qry.Parameters("StopDate").Value = Forms!frm_Bldg_Access!StopDate
    Set rs = qry.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)

'populate rs
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveLast
        rs.MoveFirst

'start report generation loop
'Currenlty outputting blank reports as well as needed ones
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        temp = rs("Supervisor")
        MyFileName = rs("Supervisor") & Format(Date, ", mmm yyyy") & ".PDF"
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_Expiring_Access", acViewReport, , "[Supervisor]='" & temp & "'"
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName
        DoCmd.Close acReport, "rpt_Expiring_Access"
        DoEvents

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If
    MsgBox "Report generation complete."
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set qry = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like your recordset has multiple records for each Supervisor. Can you run `qry_Distinct_Supervisors` directly and check if there are any duplicates?

Comment: My query is showing multiple supervisors. To fix this, I had to make the WHERE portion of the lookup query match the WHERE part of the query used for the report. Thanks @BankBuilder

Comment: Glad you fixed it!